# Compiling TSX to JS with Babel not correct

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, babeljs

I'm trying to have babel compile a folder of react tsx files into browser-readable js files in one step. Eveything seems fine, except the compiled JS output still carries the import lines from the tsx files.

I think this is a configuration problem. Here are the key files:

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      {
        "flow": false,
        "typescript": true
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/preset-typescript",
      {
        "isTSX": true,
        "allExtensions": true
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties", "react-auto-binding"]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "allowJs": true,                          /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    "outDir": "build",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "rootDir": "src",                         /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    "jsx": "react",
    "noEmit": true,

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "noImplicitAny": true,                    /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */

    /* Additional Checks */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */

    /* Advanced Options */
    "resolveJsonModule": true                 /* Include modules imported with '.json' extension */
  }
}
```

**The file I'm trying to convert (test.tsx):**

```
import * as React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const e = React.createElement;

class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { number: 1 };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>TESTING</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }

  testingTS(something: number) {}
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector("#like_button_container");
ReactDOM.render(<LikeButton />, domContainer);
```

**The babel command**

```
npx babel src --out-dir public/scripts --extensions ".tsx"
```

**The file it output (test.js):**

```
import * as React from "react";   <-- this should not be here ---
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"; <-- this should not be here ---
const e = React.createElement;

class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      number: 1
    };
  }

  render() {
    return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("div", null, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("h1", null, "TESTING"));
  }

  testingTS(something) {}

}

const domContainer = document.querySelector("#like_button_container");
ReactDOM.render( /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(LikeButton, null), domContainer);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven't set the correct output format, add [**@babel/preset-env**](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env) to tell babel what format it should use

Comment: That definitely changed things, but seems like my settings are not correct. Do you happen to know which options I need to choose?

Comment: I'm getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined". It seems babel compiled something that the browser doesn't know, to other things that the browser also doesn't know

Comment: You still need to define what environment to compile to, I would strongly suggest using [browserslist](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#browserslist-integration) and say something like `> 0.25% not dead`

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing that, and also tried all possible combos under "modules":

    "@babel/preset-env",
          {
            "targets": "> 0.25%, not dead",
            "modules": false
          }

Comment: Just realized that babel doesn't find node_modules so you also need webpack/browserify to make it work ...